# How to put ngFor and ngIf in MAT-Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table where I am displaying name.
However, I have an array of name and I want to put condition where if name type is equal to primary name then show that name on the table.
How can I achieve that?

**Code for HTML:**

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="customerSearchRecordList" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Number </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{ i + 1 }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- First Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName" >
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.individualCustomer.individualName[0].firstName }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Last Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.individualCustomer.individualName[0].lastName }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Date of birth Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfBirth">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date Of Birth</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.individualCustomer.dateOfBirth | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Gender Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="gender">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Gender</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.individualCustomer.gender }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Status Column -->
      <!-- View Button -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
      <button mat-icon-button color="#b71c1c" matTooltip="View" (click)="transferIndCustData(element)">
        <!-- <mat-icon aria-label="Delete"
          >delete</mat-icon
      > -->
        <i class="material-icons large" style="font-size: 50px">
          pageview
        </i>
      </button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**Typescript Code:**

```
 this.customer360Service.getCustbyLastName("'" + this.lastNameValue + "'").subscribe(
  data => {
    this.sampleData = data;
    this.customerSearchRecord = this.sampleData;
    this.customerSearchRecordList = new MatTableDataSource<Customer> 
    (this.customerSearchRecord);
 });
```

Comment: Mat-tables work best when supplying a vanilla datasource, that it than filters via table actions. You would be best of having the table render your original data (or intercept it before it goes to the table) or have a button on your page that updates the datasource to filter out your requirements. Alternatively, if you did want to filter this in the template, you would need to put *ngIf statements in div, wrapped around each ng-container (from memory), but again, this is not the best practice (even if it is still possible).

Comment: You need to check externally regarding your table and bind it

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, in this case we need a filtered data to be displayed on HTML. 
Hence filtering the customerSearchRecordList from typescript code before rendering on HTML would be an ideal solution.